# Ubuntu added a 1 at the end of my hdd names after upgrade(i think)

Tags: upgrade, rename

Can someone explain why my hard drive names suddenly appended a 1 at the end of the name?

Details: im using an old pc as a jellyfin server, running 20.04. No raid, jbod - Total of 11 disks, all internal. Named Movies (01 to 04), Series (01 to 03) and Anime (01 to 04). I setup my server and everything was ok.
But it would appear that after i upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 (the only major change from one day to the next) the names of the disks appear as Movies011 , Movies021 etc, i.e. the os arbitrarily assigned a 1 at the end!

Why? And why do the old hdd names appear on Files but with a red x?
Can i safely rename? Can i delete/erase the old hdd names?
Or do i just tell jellyfin to index the drives with the new names?
Will they change again after the next update?

Please help me?

Comment: This seems like an issue with Jellyfin more than an issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: Does jellyfin have the power to do that? i have had 2 previous instances of a jellyfin server (one in windows and one in OMV) and this is a first so i assumed it was the ubuntu upgrade

Comment: "*why do the old hdd names appear on Files but with a red x*" This seems strong evidence that your hard drives failed to mount and were *re-mounted*, not renamed. In turn, that suggests you are perhaps chasing the wrong problem. Look for common causes of failed mounting: Filesystem errors, I/O errors, wrong UUIDs, etc.